# Picking a popular vs unpopular friend

Tags: probability

There are 2 types of people on a social media platform: type A has 80 friends, type B has 20 friends. 
We assume that half of the people are Type A, and half of the people are Type B.

The expected number of friends for a person is then $\frac{1}{2} \times 80 + \frac{1}{2} \times 20 = 50$.

What is the probability I pick type A friend among my friends? This question is taken from this Udacity [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRmATovfU04&feature=emb_logo).

Their answer is [explained here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?&v=H1RNw27qRrw&feature=emb_logo). They state the probability of picking type A friend among your friends is $\frac{4}{5}$.

I understand their reasoning, and it makes sense - it is much more likely to have a "popular" i.e. type A friend among your friends than "unpopular" i.e. type B friend, simply because their probability of having you as a friend is higher.

But I am wondering why we can't reason like this:

- type A and type B people are equally likely as stated above. So among my friends, I am as likely to pick type A person as type B person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> type $A$ and type $B$ people are equally likely as stated above. So among my friends, I am as likely to pick type $A$ person as type $B$ person?

No. This does not follow. Your confusion is this:

*Among all people*, there are indeed just as many of type $A$ as of type $B$. Indeed, it is in this sense that $A$ and $B$ are equally likely.

But *among all friends*, there are $4$ times as many $A$'s than $B$'s. So, picking from all friends, you can expect $4$ out of $5$ to be of type $A$

Answer (score 1):

In the overall population if a person is selected at random, they are equally likely to be Type A or Type B. However, your friends circle is not representative of the overall population.

It's like say half of all people in the world are rich and half are poor. A guy walks up to you in the street and gives you one dollar for your service. Is he equally likely to be rich or poor? No, he is not a random representative of the population